# Wordpress plugin Parse error /

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone please help? I am new to wordpress, I successfully installed a plugin and it was working fine, then I got the following error, and I can no longer activist or delete the plug causing this error. I have not been able to find a way to completely delete the plugin so that I can reinstall it again?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'constants' (T_STRING) in /home3/tenrub/public_html/startupqld.org/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/all-in-one-event-calendar.php on line 40

Answer (score 0):

When the interface of a wordpress site is blank apart from an ugly error message, you need to log in to the server hosting your wordpress site and delete the plugin from there. Logging in means using telnet, ssh, or ftp. Your host may also offer some other web-based method to add and delete files from the file system.

Once you are in, you need to go to the directory: **/home3/tenrub/public_html/startupqld.org/wp-content/plugins/** and delete the **all-in-one-event-calendar** directory.

You will then be able to log in to the admin area and continue working.

Does that make sense?